Работа с папками каналов на python (telethon)
Мне нужна помощь:
Пример ссылки: https://t.me/addlist/_88Hua77fXU1OGQ0
Мне нужно чтобы сессия telethon добавляла папку с каналами
"Добавить" имеется ввиду 

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, получилось найти решение?
